# AsyncTaskLoader - how to?

Tags: java, android, ant, android-asynctask

I use loader to  do task in back ground in method loadInBackground i added for loop to print log in logcat 50 time , so when i click the button start print log in logcat

but when i click the button i don't have any action and i don't have ant error , what is problem ?

```
 mainActicity 
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
      TextView textView;
      android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            loaderManager=getLoaderManager();
            textView=findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
            if (loaderManager.getLoader(0) ==null){
                loaderManager.initLoader(0,null,this);

            }
        }




    public void StartMysynstack (View view){
        loaderManager.initLoader(0,null,this);
    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new Myloader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<String> loader, String s) {
          textView.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<String> loader) {

    }

}
```

my loader

```
public class Myloader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {
 int i;

    public Myloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String loadInBackground() {
        for( i=0;i<=100;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                Log.d("waad","loadInBackground"+i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Task result";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try calling it manually.

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
```

so according to your code you can make following changes.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loaderManager=getLoaderManager();
        textView=findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        if (loaderManager.getLoader(0) ==null){
            loaderManager.initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();;

        }
    }
```